# Is determinant of a representation polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$, and $\pi: V \to End (V)$ a linear mapping. I want to show that the determinant of $\pi(x)$ is a polynomial on $V$.

**My attempt**

It is obvious that the determinant is just made of sums and products if we fix a basis, but that is not a rigorous argument and I don't see how it is free of our choice of basis.

Comment: What do you mean by "a representation" ? What are the group and the action group ? What is $x$ ? Why is the image in $End(V)$ and not in $GL(V)$ ?

Comment: what is a "polynomial on $V$" ????????????

Comment: @mercio Tone it done a bit, will you? A "polynomial on $F^n$" is a polynomial in $F[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$. A "polynomial on $V$" is just the base-free version of this, i.e. the set of polynomial function is canonically identified with the symmetric algebra $Sym(V^\ast)$. This is a ring of functions because you can plug in any $v\in V$ and it consists of polynomial functions because it is freely generated by linear forms which (after choice of a basis) just correspond to linear combination ofs the standard monomials in the standard polynomial ring.

Comment: @maxim: Choosing a basis is perfectly valid for a rigorous proof. There is not fault in your argument. Nothing in your claim was basis dependent, so that there is no base-independence to show in the proof either. By the way: There is no need to have the two vector spaces be equal, i.e exactly the same argument also holds for maps $\pi: V\to End(W)$.